# PostgreSQL - Cast generated column type

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I tried to create generated column from other JSON type column with
`ALTER TABLE "Invoice" ADD COLUMN created Integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (data ->> 'created') STORED;`

When I execute this I get error
`ERROR:  column "created" is of type integer but default expression is of type text HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. SQL state: 42804`

I tried to cast it with CAST function and :: operator but with no lack. Is there any way to do it? Or maybe I should generate this column differently?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about converting the value to an int?

```
ALTER TABLE "Invoice" ADD COLUMN created Integer
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( (data ->> 'created')::int ) STORED;
```